# How to find out which process is consuming "wait CPU" (i.e. I/O blocked)

Tags: linux, command-line

With `top` it's easy to find out how much CPU each job uses. However, I want to hunt down a job that causes a high wait CPU. Is there a way to find out which jobs are blocked on I/O?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

[iotop](http://guichaz.free.fr/iotop/) and [latencytop](http://www.latencytop.org/) may be helpful.  Neither gives exactly "CPU wait time caused by a process" -- I'm not sure it even makes sense, because the CPU can and does go off to service other processes while waiting for IO -- but these two tools give overviews of (respectively) system I/O traffic and scheduling delays.

Comment: both tools look nice, but the server I'm on can't easily be patched or upgraded to >2.6.20, so they don't work for me. but I'll keep them for future reference :)

Comment: The link to LatencyTOP.org is dead - no root DNS records. The project appears to be dead, no commits since 2009.

Answer (score 66):

The processes blocked on IO are the ones marked as `D` in the status column (`S` column in top).

Comment: This should probably be the accepted answer here as it's more easily attainable as an aid to finding the culprit process.

Answer (score 42):

To be more precise, use this command can easily find out which processes are "eating" your CPU cycles:

`while true; do date; ps auxf | awk '{if($8=="D") print $0;}'; sleep 1; done`

This url could be helpful: [Linux Wait IO Problem](http://www.chile-offshore.com/en/interesting-articles/126-linux-wait-io-problem)

Comment: D : Uninterruptible sleep (usually IO)

Comment: watch -n 1 "(ps aux | awk '\$8 ~ /D/  { print \$0 }')"

Comment: @abkrim: nice!  I like the '-d' option for watch, making your solution:  watch -d -n 1 "(ps aux | awk '\$8 ~ /D/ { print \$0 }')"

Comment: Just wanted to chime in and say that I like using uptime instead of date, as that will give you both the time and the load. This is pretty helpful because it allows you to watch leading/trailing load along with the ps output.

Comment: I'm so immature

Answer (score 4):

Do a top, then shift F , then choose m or n, will sort the listing of processes by CPU time used.